# String comparison C - strcmp()

Tags: c, string, comparison

I'm trying to compare two strings, but I fail achieving that. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    float a = 1231.23123;
    char b[32];
    sprintf(b, "%f", a);
    printf("%s\n", b);
    char c[32] = "1231.23123";
    if (strcmp(c, b) == 0){
        printf("SUCCES\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("DIFFER\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
1231.231201
DIFFER
```

Comment: But the two strings are clearly different, so `strcmp()` is working as it should.

Comment: Try printing BOTH c and b strings...

Comment: Oh..... so my sprinf works wrong...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two strings are clearly different, so `strcmp()` is working as it should.

The issue is that `1231.23123` cannot be represented as a `float`. In fact, the nearest number that *can* be represented as a `float` is `1231.231201171875`, which is what you're seeing (rounded by `sprintf()` to six decimal places).

Answer (score 4):

If you want a set number of digits to compare against in a string, use the precision specifier in `sprintf` - `%.5f`, and as others have pointed out, the number you've picked cannot be represented by a `float`, but can be represented by a `double`. i.e.

```
double a = 1231.23123;
char b[32];
sprintf(b, "%.5f",a);
```

Comment: Which leads to the question - Why does it [add a 0 at the end](https://ideone.com/iZg7sm) if you omit `.5`?

Comment: @Dukeling - Because `%f` prints 6 decimal places unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: So I think the more generic solution would be to have the string be `"1231.231230"` (and omitting the `.5`).

Comment: @Dukeling - yes, if you always want 6 places in a string, but it'd mean comparing strings like `"1.000000"` instead of `"1.0"` with `%.1f`

Answer (score 3):

It's because the precision of float cannot support so many digits. So b is not "1231.23123". In my test, it's "1231.231201".

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing these 2 strings here:

```
1231.23123
1231.231201
```

which are different indeed, thus `strcmp` returns non-zero value.

The actual problem here is that when you do `float a = 1231.23123;`, the number you want to store in `a` can't be represented as a `float`, the nearest number that can be represented as a `float` is `1231.231201171875` in this case. Have a look at [OMG Ponies!!! (Aka Humanity: Epic Fail)](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) ;)

---

To solve your problem I would start with using `double` instead of `float` to get more precise accuracy. Then you could specify the precision (`%.5lf`) while printing this number into the string to make sure that the number is rounded just like you need it:

```
double d = 1231.23123;
char str[32];
sprintf(str, "%.5lf", d);
// strcmp(str, "1231.23123") would return 0 here
```