# Compare Strings Alphabetically

Tags: c++11

I have a homework-related question.

I have an array of objects. One of the properties of each of these objects is a string. I need to be able to sort the array alphabetically with respect to this string. I have the sort function written; I've tested it with integers in place of the string. The sorting works fine. However, I don't know how to compare two strings alphabetically. How would I do this?

Comment: Are your strings `std::string` or null-terminated `char` arrays? The answers are different depending on the type of your "strings".

Comment: Then comparing two `std::string` is as simple as comparing two `int`. Just use `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, etc.

Comment: And this will give an alphabetical answer?

Comment: Yes, it will compare two `std::string` alphabetically (lexicographical or "dictionary" order). Note that it's case-sensitive. If you need a case-insensitive compare just search here on SO, that's been asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use existing string compare functions, try to use the ASCII values of each letter for comparison. For example, 'A' = 41 and 'B' = 42, so 'B' > 'A'

Thus, if you have 2 strings like

`char str1[] = "abc";
char str2[] = "def";`

you can compare them positionwise, so you may start first with something like

`if(str1[0] < str2[0])
...`

`if(str1[1] < str2[1])
...`

and so on. Of course, you can improve this through using a `for` or `while` loop

Comment: I haven't been able to find existing string compare functions. Do you have documentation for them? I'm aware that this is a really, really basic question, but I've been looking for hours - I just don't know what to look for.

Comment: Bryan Chen mentioned it, the strcmp. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430562/string-comparison-c-strcmp for definition and example.