# String comparision in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to test the name.The users need to type name again when the name had already existed.But the program clashes when run.Thanks for your help!

```
{
#define MAX 3
char *Mystr2[40];
char Mystr1[40];
int i,k,j;

for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
{
    printf("Enter the name:");
    gets(Mystr1);

    Mystr2[j]=Mystr1;//i want to save the string into Mystr[0].[1]

    for (j=0;j<i;j++)//Test the name whether it is same or not
    {
        if(strcmp(Mystr2[j],Mystr2[i])==0)
        {
            printf("They are the same");
                            i--;
                            break;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: have a look at http://www.wikihow.com/Compare-Two-Strings-in-C-Programming and : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430562/string-comparison-c-strcmp

Comment: @yunas based on the code he's shown, while he has other issues, how to compare strings is not one of them.

Comment: And don't use `gets`!

Comment: I saw the link.But when i have more than 2 strings.I can't think exactly.I change the gets to fgets.

Answer (score 3):

Your crash is because `Mystr2[j]=Mystr1`, I thnk you meant `Mystr2[i]=Mystr1`.

The logic will not work anyway, since `Mystr2` will always point to what is in `Mystr1` at that moment; change the declaration to `char Mystr2[MAX][40]` and `strcpy()` into it.

Comment: Thanks you! I can run the test.